# Haar-detector: what are rejectLevels and levelWeights used for?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I have tried to find the usage of `rejectLevels` and `levelWeights` in the documentation but those are non-documented. Why can `detectMultiScale()` return them? Are they not constant properties of the cascades?

Comment: Please refer to this [thread] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378932/undocumented-grouprectangles-variants-in-opencv

Comment: Here it is in the OpenCV docs: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#accf96d130d9f3cf4c58bf445b7861c19