# Undocumented groupRectangles variants in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

In cascadedetect.cpp in OpenCV, there are several variants of `groupRectangles` function:

```
void groupRectangles(std::vector<Rect>& rectList, int groupThreshold, double eps);
void groupRectangles(std::vector<Rect>& rectList, std::vector<int>& weights, int groupThreshold, double eps);
void groupRectangles(std::vector<Rect>& rectList, std::vector<int>& rejectLevels, std::vector<double>& levelWeights, int groupThreshold, double eps);
```

But in the [OpenCV document](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles), only the first variant is documented clearly, the second variant is mentioned but the `weights` argument is not explained. The third isn't even mentioned.

Can anyone explain the meanings of `weights`, `rejectLevels`, and `levelWeights`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the `groupRectangles` source code and understood the meanings of these parameters to some degree.

`groupRectangles` is defined in cascadedetect.cpp, which is used by traincascade project in OpenCV. This project uses viola-jones's cascaded adaboost framework to detect objects, thus it has several cascade stages, and each of them is a strong classifier. The cascade classifier by default outputs positive only if the input sample passed every stage, but you can also set it to output the index of stage at which the sample is rejected if you want to plot a ROC curve.

So `rejectLevels` means the index of stage at which the rectangle is rejected. According to source code, the effect of `weight` is same as `rejectLevels`.

The above two parameters may not be very practical for us, but `levelWeights` is sometimes useful. It's originally the score of the rectangle outputted by the stage which rejects it, but we can use it for a more general purpose. If every rectangle has a score(no matter where it comes from), and we want to get the scores of grouped rectangles, the documented variant of `groupRectangles` won't help us. We must use the third one, with `rejectLevels` set to zeros:

```
vector<int> levels(wins.size(), 0);
groupRectangles(wins, levels, scores, groupThreshold, eps);
```

In which `scores` is the scores of `wins`. They have same size.

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain what does it mean by the parameter "eps"? Thanks.

Comment: @BonderWu, the parameter "eps" is explained in the [official document](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles).